# Permissions not getting carried over when visiting a new page while using facebook's php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am using the following code to get permissions for my app(the code is in index.php)-

```
   <?php
  require_once "sdk/facebook.php";

   $fbconfig['appid'] = "333446170045623";
  $fbconfig['secret'] = "9ea7b92bc7eac852a3900e1d7931c34d";

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $fbconfig['appid'],
        'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

   $user = $facebook->getUser();

  if (!$user) { /* If user not found, authenticate */
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename?sk=app_333446170045623'
        ));
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
   }

  $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
      ?>
```

Now, there's a link on the page which takes the user to a select.php page. There I have tried to use the following code to get info about the current user-

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

I have placed the same permission retreival code as the index.php page on this page.

However, I get the following error on this page-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /server/html/appname/sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1106
```

I have tried the various suggested solutions but they dont seem to work. How do I use $facebook->api('/me') to get the info on this page? (btw I am using facebook's latest php sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but using the `getAccessToken()` method before using

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

will stop giving the error.

Comment: I'm having the same error. I can't seem to figure out what you mean. I've tried the same answer that you've got here but I can't get it to work on my second page. Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: @Navnath kindly go through the language flow before you edit anything.. u just made it worse(read the whole answer in one flow)...the urge to edit something is compelling..just think twice if its really needed..just a friendly advice..

Answer (score 0):

If this is a native facebook app, the you have 2 options. You can set the target of all your links to be the parent frame and append your new url on the end e.g http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp/next.php , alternatively, you can include the js-sdk on the page to handle the login and logout events with window.reload. If this is a native app, most likely the correct data isn't being sent from facebook, resulting in the signed_request etc. being lost and you lose the access token.

If it is a website application, I would also suggest using the javascript sdk on the page.

so something similar to this just below the body tag on all your pages

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>               
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $app_id; ?>', 
      cookie: true, 
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      setTimeout('window.location.reload()',0);
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
     setTimeout('window.location.reload()',0);
    });
  };
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=433871385166";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```