# Facebook PHP SDK Not Retaining Value of Variable Across Multi Page iFrame App

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

My question is regarding Facebook apps. I have an iFrame app and I am using the Facebook PHP SDK to get the user's information and display via variables. Basically there is an array which is set up like this:

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$config = array();
  $config['appId'] = '562494063776100';
  $config['secret'] = '83f3c580f0b4f9ddca7cd13e1386b733';
  $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
  $config['cookie'] = true;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
  die;
}
```

Then I can access the variables from the open graph like $user_profile['name'] for example. It works fine on the initial load but then I lose the value of $user. The app is a multi page iframe app meaning it's like a little mini website with three pages. The user goes to the welcome page, then can go to a vote page or an enter page. I just load the facebook.php and info in the first page because it was giving me errors when I had a connect.php (which has the facebook SDK info as well as my MySQL log in info) in the other files. I suppose it because facebook.php is being called more than once?

Now the issue is that I can access the $user_profile on the main page but can't on the other pages. I'm assuming this is because it's not querying the facebook.php file but I can't put the facebook.php file on those pages because I get an error. The error it gives me is whatever I put in the "die" section of the if statement. Basically $user is not getting set. I wanted to try to avoid using the Javascript SDK so I can keep everything server side.

I saw this post:
[Permissions not getting carried over when visiting a new page while using facebook's php sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906475/permissions-not-getting-carried-over-when-visiting-a-new-page-while-using-facebo)
Which is close to the same problem but not exactly the same. Thanks for the help!